# How can I add just the second elements in lists of pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have two lists of pairs:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
b = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}};
```

And I want to add the second element of every pair in `b` to the second element of every pair in `a`, so the expected result would be `{{1, 8}, {3, 12}}`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lst1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}};

lst1a = lst1;
lst1a[[All, 2]] *= 2;
lst1a
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}}

```
lst2 = {{3, 5}, {10, 2}};

lst1b = lst1;
lst1b[[All, 2]] += lst2[[All, 2]];
lst1b
```

> {{1, 7}, {2, 6}}

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = Module[{l = #}, l[[;; , 2]] += #2[[;; , 2]]; l] &;

f1[lst1, lst1]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}}

```
f1[lst1, lst2]
```

> {{1, 7}, {2, 6}}

```
f1[a, b] (* a and b from m_goldberg's answer *)
```

> {{1, 10}, {3, 14}, {5, 18}}

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Module[{l2 = #2}, l2[[All, 1]] = 0; # + l2] &;

{f1[lst1, lst1] == f2[lst1, lst1], f1[lst1, lst2] == f2[lst1, lst2], f1[a, b] == f2[a, b]}
```

> {True, True, True}

Answer (score 10):

I like to do this kind of thing by writing a custom function to perform the the desired operation on two given pairs. I then map this function over the two lists with `MapThread`. In most cases, by using Mathematica's argument-pattern destructuring, the custom function can be expressed extremely simply. This is one of those cases.

The custom function is

```
f[{x_, y_}, {_, z_}] := {x, y + z}
```

Note that the righthand side is a literal expression of the desired result.

Now let's contrive some test data. I write the generator so that two lists of pairs can easily be given any length.

```
With[{n = 3}, {a, b} = Partition[Partition[Range[4 n], 2], n]];
a
b
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
> {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}
> ```

Now we `MapThread` the function `f` over `a` and `b`.

```
MapThread[f, {a, b}]
```

> `{1, 10}, {3, 14}, {5, 18}}`

Comment: +1 to how you worded this, I enjoyed being able to read and follow along with what you did! Going to show this to my first class of wolfram recruits tomorrow :))

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}} + ({{1, 2}, {2, 4}} /. {x_,y _} -> {0, y})

(* {{2, 4}, {4, 8}}  *)
```

or this

```
(# + (# /. {x_, y_} -> {0, y})) &[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}}]

(* {{1, 2}, {4, 8}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}};

MapAt[2 # &, {All, 2}] @ list
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}}

Comment: Hi @eldo! It's been a while... :)

Comment: Yes, nice to see you again :}

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}};
```

Adding the second elements from each pair of the same list:

```
{#[[1]], 2 #[[2]]} & /@ list1
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}}

Adding the second element from a different list:

```
list2 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]] + #[[2, 2]]} & /@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

> {{1, 2 + b}, {2, 4 + d}}

Answer (score 4):

In situations like this, [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) can be useful

```
a + b.{{0,0},{0,1}}
```

> {{1, 8}, {3, 12}}

```
ga={{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
gb={{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}

ga + gb.{{0,0},{0,1}}
```

> {{1, 10}, {3, 14}, {5, 18}}

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}};
MapThread[{First[#1], Last[#1] + Last[#2]} &, {lst, lst}]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}}